# Как на React сделать вертикальное меню с выделением элемента меню?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Новичок в реакте, поэтому надеюсь на ваши советы
Что я имею ввиду:
у меня есть меню, нужно менять цвет у пунктов меню при клике.
Набросал код js: jsfiddle.net/c6pu17e3/

Сделал в реакте, а как дальше делать незнаю:  jsfiddle.net/c61uhrk8/

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать  react-router-dom 
там есть NavLink и ему можно задать activeClassName когда роут активен
пример: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

или сделать по индексу так:

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {
  menuList = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      href: '#home'
    },
    {
      title: 'Portfolio',
      href: '#portfolio'
    },
    {
      title: 'About',
      href: '#about'
    },
    {
      title: 'Contact',
      href: '#contact'
    }
  ];
  
  state = {
    activeIndex: 0
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="menu">
          <ul>
            {
              this.menuList.map((item, index) => (
                <li key={index} onClick={() => this.setState({activeIndex: index})}>
                  <a class={this.state.activeIndex === index ? "menu-active": ""} href="#home">{ item.title }</a>
                </li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Код выше не работает, Пишет ошибку, я же скинул пример, нии чего нету,